# python service access to ajax call , CORS error

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x, ajax

I'm getting lost with this problem,
i have a service written in python that i need to access from a web page with an ajax call

the python code is as follows:

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
    
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/api/v1/resources/device/all', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def api_all():

[...]
 response = jsonify(result)
 response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    
 return response,status_code
```

and the ajax call is:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        url: AddressWS + '/api/v1/resources/device/all?type=A',
        success: function (result) {
//.,...
        }
    });
```

The error is ever

> ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource.

the web application is under IIS .
the question is :
if I set 0.0.0.0 as address in python script, which address should I call in the web application ?
i try to machine ipv4 address but don't run.
how i fix the cors problem, i seem to have correctly included the flask libraries.

Thanks everyone for the kind replies

Comment: Try cors setting before app.run.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not configured properly in your code. Please find below the code with the correct CORS configuration.

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Api  
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/api/v1/resources/device/all', methods=['GET'])
def api_all():
 [...]
 response = jsonify(result)
 status_code = 'some code'
 return response,status_code
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Hi, the error is the same, i copied exactly the code that have you post....
I'm certainly missing something, I'm newbie of python ....

Comment: [...] at this point u have to define the result or implement the API functionality.

Comment: ok thanks to all 
it run correctly  with the Vimlesh answers, sorry for my  late answer

Comment: @Franz78x happy to know the solution work for you. please accept the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in my case it works ,

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: AddressWS + '/api/v1/resources/device/all?type=A',
        cors: true,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        secure: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //.,...
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```